# How to get (ancient) dates with `beforechrist`localisation?

Tags: biblatex, date

I would like to get the date(era) of this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style = archaeologie,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{de:re:publica,
    author  = {Cicero},
    title      = {De re publica},
    date     = {-0054/-0051},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
  \fullcite{de:re:publica}
\end{document}
```

[image]

as described in table 5 of the `biblatex` documentation:

[image]

How can I achieve tihs?

Comment: Option `dateera=christian`?

Comment: Are you sure you want Christian dates?

Comment: The style you are using prints the era string in some cases, but, in your example, using `dateera-christian` will produce '55-51' since both years are part of the same era. If the second was a common era year, you'd get '55 BC -51'. I assume you are using this style because you are publishing or hoping to publish in a journal which uses it. Is the style correct for those journals?

Comment: @cfr If I'm not mistaken, LukasCB is the developer/maintainer of the style.

Comment: @gusbrs Then the question seems odd since the style seems designed not to do what its designer asks. (I only looked quickly, though - perhaps I'm missing something.) I mean, the style has to make use of the era information and the settings, obviously. So, if you want a style you're designing to use it the same way standard styles do, you have to implement it the same way as they do, I'd think.

Comment: LukasCB, as far as I was able to trace, the style sets the option `alldates=comp`. Using both `dateera=christian` and `alldates=long` would give you dateera information there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that [`english-archaeologie.lbx`](https://github.com/LukasCBossert/biblatex-archaeologie/blob/e6cd56d3f82f74ad4d7c2fa5b9f551aeede2743b/english-archaeologie.lbx) has `\dateeraprint{#2}` instead of `\dateeraprint{#2year}`. This is similar to [issue #679 at the `biblatex` bug tracker](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/679). The code in `english-archaeologie.lbx` was based on an older version of the `biblatex` core macros from before the fix.

I have submitted a pull request (https://github.com/LukasCBossert/biblatex-archaeologie/pull/146) with the necessary changes.

---

I should probably add that all of this is under the assumption that you use

```
dateera=christian
```

or `dateera=secular` if you prefer the non-Christian denominations, as suggested by @gusbrs in the [very first comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435750/how-to-get-ancient-dates-with-beforechristlocalisation/435775#comment1092783_435750).

Comment: Ah! It was in the `.lbx`! (+1)